# filter a mysql pivot query without losing filtered fields for selected records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pivot table to link sheet music titles to a list of parts (music for specific instruments)

For example one song might have lead guitar, keyboard and drums, as you'd expect the pivot table has two entries for the song pointing to the appropriate song parts...

I have a query that concatenates all the part names for a song into a single field
so you'd get "lead guitar, keyboard, drums" in a single field

Here is the query:

```
select 
    songs.title, 
    group_concat(distinct songpart.partName separator ', ') as parts 
from 
    songpart,
    songpartpivot,
    songs 
where 
    songs.id=songpartpivot.songid and 
    songpartpivot.partid=songpart.id 
group by 
    (songs.id)
```

This does just what I want, however I'm having trouble filtering the query, for example I might want all the songs with drum parts, simply adding

```
and songpartpivot.partid = ?
```

to the WHERE clause does actually select for all the songs with a particular, however I then only get the (single) selected for part in the concatenated field, so where there should be

```
Lead Guitar, Bass Guitar, Drums
```

I see only

```
Bass Guitar
```

when selecting all songs with a Bass Guitar part

How to a select for values in the pivot table or on other fields of the songs table, while still being able to see all parts for selected records...

by request:

```
mysql> describe songs;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe songpartpivot;
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| songid | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| partid | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe songpart;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    | auto_increment |
| partName | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. Also, do no use implict (comma-) join syntax. Always use explicit JOIN syntax. Then half your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need post aggregation filtration

```
group by 
    (songs.id)
having SUM(songpartpivot.partid = ?)>0
```

Comment: two working answers - which to accept... can you explain why the SUM and why the query doesn't recognise the field without it?

Comment: HAVING is used to filter the grouped data..so it selects all groups which contain partid=?.

Comment: but why SUM ? - why does SUM "see" partid where as having doesn't ?

Comment: ended up accepting this one because its the easiest to find different combination of parts for example with some and without another

Comment: SUM ...well sums all the instances for each group where a partyid with value x exists.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to envision without seeing the DDL but perhaps this constraint would work in place of the one that you're trying to use:

```
and songs.id in ( select songid from songpart where songpart.partid=?)
```

Comment: two working answers - which to accept... is your solution slower somehow because of the sub query? can you expand a little on how the IN statement is working?

Comment: Yes, the subquery will slow this query down